# Undefined in a textarea

Tags: jquery

The following code is to do the following:

First, create a div class=words, and then a hidden textarea with id txtarea and a button with class btn2.  What I want to happen is:

The page opens with the a paragraph in div words which will fade out, leaving the hidden textarea and button to appear.  The user is to then input text in the textarea, press the button, and the textarea and button disappear and are replaced with the div words, now with text entered by the user from the textarea.

Everything works well until the paragraph fades out.  What I get then is the textarea with the word "undefined".  If I type in any text and hit the botton, as expected the textarea disappears, along with the button, but "undefined " remains.  Note that the settimeout was included since I kept getting the javascript to start before the paragraph loaded, even though I thought the $document.ready function was to prevent that.  Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> this is the title</title>
<style>
    p {
        font-family: "Times New Roman",TImes, serif;
    }
    pre{
        white-space:pre-wrap;font-family: "Times New Roman",TImes, serif
    }
    .words {
        position:absolute;width:auto;height:auto;top:260px;left:265px;right:225px;text-align:center;color:black;
        font-size: 60px;
    }
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("p").fadeOut();
            $("#newtext").fadeIn();
            var area = document.getElementById("newtext");
            str = area.value
            $('.words').html("<pre>" + str + "</pre>")
            $(".btn2").click(function(){
                $("#newtext").fadeOut()
            });
        },5000);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class ="words">
        <p> When this fades out, enter text.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="newtext" style="display:none" >
        <textarea rows="50" cols="200" id = "txtArea"  > </textarea>
        <button class="btn2">SEE YOUR TEXT</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried adding an initial value to the textarea but it just prints along with the big undefined.

Comment: why don't you add your comment to the questions? Also please edit it and format it better, it is currently like a wall of text.

Comment: I added the comment after posting since I just thought of trying that to answer the question.  I've reformatted

Answer (score 0):

Why are you mixing jQuery and non-jQuery?  Don't do this:

```
var area = document.getElementById("newtext");
str = area.value
```

Do this:

```
var area = $('#newtext');
str = area.val();
```

Note that you had a missing semicolon in `area.value` above, which is also probably not helping.  You're also missing a semicolon after `$('.words').html("<pre>" + str + "</pre>")`.

You should run JSLint on your code to spot problems like missing semicolons.

**EDIT:** Your function is setting the content of the div with class `words` to the starting value of the textarea, which is empty -- that's why your text disappears.  [This jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gDEV2/1/) works, based on my understanding of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Almost there.  Followed all your advice and all works well much longer.  However, after typing text in textarea and pressing the button, everything disappears, including this next text in the div words which I though would now show.  What am I not understanding?  Thanks